# Why do we need BEGIN END (execution section) in last portion for an Anonymus block?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, anonymous-function, oracle19c

When I try to run this code

```
DECLARE
TYPE type_a IS
    TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
output NUMBER := 1;

FUNCTION fun_2 RETURN type_a IS
    dum type_a;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        employee_id
    BULK COLLECT
    INTO dum
    FROM
        employees;

    RETURN dum;
END fun_2;

PROCEDURE proc_1 AS
BEGIN
    NULL;
END;
```

I am getting below error:

> Error report - ORA-06550: line 22, column 8: PLS-00103: Encountered
> the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
>
> begin function pragma procedure
> 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
> *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
> *Action:

But when i add BEGIN END  at last its working fine

```
    DECLARE
    TYPE type_a IS
        TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    output NUMBER := 1;

    FUNCTION fun_2 RETURN type_a IS
        dum type_a;
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            employee_id
        BULK COLLECT
        INTO dum
        FROM
            employees;

        RETURN dum;
    END fun_2;

    PROCEDURE proc_1 AS
    BEGIN
        NULL;
    END;

BEGIN
    null ;
END;
```

I got the answer but Why is this ? I mean How the code is being executed and why is it needed?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  You're declaring a function and a procedure that are local to an anonymous PL/SQL block so they disappear once the block finishes.  Since you aren't calling them, there is no point in declaring them.  My guess is that you want to create a stored procedure and a store function (persistent objects that can be called from other blocks) or a package with the procedure and function (which would also persist them in the database).

Comment: @Justin Cave i don't want  stored procedures/function  just  i need to know why the error  is happening in first code and not in second code . This is not a real scenario nor any task i got, i am just trying to solve interview questions . i just want to know how these 2 code works. :)

Comment: An anonymous block needs an executable section.  Otherwise, it's just declarations and it doesn't make sense to have declarations for a transient block with nothing to execute.  I'm not sure what you're looking for other than "PL/SQL doesn't allow anonymous blocks that just declare local variables and local objects but that don't have executable sections because that's not a sensible thing to want"

Comment: @ Justin Cave "An anonymous block needs an executable section" now i understand why i need it ... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An PL/SQL block has the structure `DECLARE ... BEGIN ... END;`. The `DECLARE` is optional if you want to declare any variables, etc. but the `BEGIN ... END;` is mandatory.

If we start with a simple block and build up:

```sql
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
/
```

Is the simplest PL/SQL statement. You then declare a type:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE type_a IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
/
```

and a variable:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE type_a IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  output NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
/
```

Then you `DECLARE` a function; this includes its own PL/SQL `BEGIN ... END;` block that will be nested within the `DECLARE` section of the anonymous outer block:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE type_a IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  output NUMBER := 1;

  FUNCTION fun_2 RETURN type_a IS
    dum type_a;
  BEGIN
    SELECT employee_id
    BULK COLLECT INTO dum
    FROM employees;

    RETURN dum;
  END fun_2;
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
/
```

Then you declare a procedure; again this includes its own PL/SQL `BEGIN ... END;` block that will be nested within the `DECLARE` section of the anonymous outer block after the function:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE type_a IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  output NUMBER := 1;

  FUNCTION fun_2 RETURN type_a IS
    dum type_a;
  BEGIN
    SELECT employee_id
    BULK COLLECT INTO dum
    FROM employees;

    RETURN dum;
  END fun_2;

  PROCEDURE proc_1 AS
  BEGIN
    NULL;
  END proc_1;
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
/
```

Back to your question:

> why is it needed?

Because, otherwise you have two `BEGIN ... END;` blocks for the function and procedure nested within the `DECLARE` section starting from the first line but no `BEGIN ... END;` that matches that `DECLARE` on the first line.

Using consistent indentation would help spot this.

Comment: @ MTO I am so dump :) i never thought of the " BEGIN END"  of anonymous block. But you understand what i was trying to ask  , Thanks bro